# Spring Security: Error during artifact deployment caused by <filter> and <filter-mapping> sections in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have small project, now i want to put some Spring Security on it.
After running project in logs i have:

```html
[2020-03-06 11:59:57,142] Artifact khn:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
06-Mar-2020 11:59:57.278 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [0.1]. Default version will be used.
06-Mar-2020 11:59:58.351 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-Mar-2020 12:00:01.154 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
06-Mar-2020 12:00:01.155 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
06-Mar-2020 12:00:01.167 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2020-03-06 12:00:01,175] Artifact khn:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
06-Mar-2020 12:00:06.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]
06-Mar-2020 12:00:06.698 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager] has finished in [28] ms
```

If i comment following lines in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Tomcat is starting properly, but Spring Security is not working.
Do You have any idea how to make Spring Security works in this case?

This is my configuration files:

web.xml

```
<web-app  version="0.1"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>khn</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="application"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="application"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/khn"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>
```

and spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**"
                   access="hasRole('admin')" />

    <!-- user-defined login form redirection -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error" />

    <!-- logout url -->
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />

    <!-- csrf disabled -->
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query=
                                   "select email,password from users where email=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query=
                                   "select u.email, r.name from users u, role r, user_roles ur where u.id = ur.user_id and ur.roles_id = r.id and u.email =?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

and whole repository: https://github.com/mtpx/khn/tree/spring_security

Answer (score 1):

Answer is:
missing import spring-security.xml in applicationContext